# accessible carousel/slider required

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, xhtml

After several hours of searching i still cannot find the desired carousel/slider. [This](http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/svwt/index.html) is actually what i need but its not accessible in that, once javascript is disabled in the browser, everything disappers. Basically, i need a jquery infinite carousel or slider that shows say 4 thumbnails, the larger picture and two buttons to move the thumbnails left and right...Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: well if javascript is **disabled** it wont ever work

Comment: @Neal - Not true.  Properly written semantic markup with javascript can accomplish these things.

Comment: @John. if javascript is disabled. javascript **won't work**

Comment: @Neal.  Bleh.  Look at something like jQuery PrettyPhoto... it utilizes semantic markup to create a nice lightbox-style image viewer... however, it is designed semantically, and will continue to provide baseline support without Javascript.  This is what the Op is referring to.

Comment: As Neal states if JavaScript is disabled it will never work. Your only option is to either accomplish this with a page refresh or an embedded iframe.

Comment: @Neal, when javascript is disabled, yes, it may not function as expected but the layout should still be there [e.g](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/image-rotator/) i would have used this, only that it does not have the buttons to control the thumbnails

Comment: @Gables - Well, I understand your question, even if nobody else does (you'd think that since semantic JS was the hot topic du jour of like 3 years ago, that people would get it more).  In answer to your question, I'd recommend just building it from scratch.  It isn't that hard.

Comment: @John, thanks for your response, i am fairly new to jquery and only understand the basics hence, the reason why i would rather a tried and tested method(plugin). moreover, i haven't got much time... :(

Answer (score 1):

[This carousel](http://se-katc.appspot.com) is unobtrusive -i.e. shows the thumbnails with JS disabled, and could be configured to show 4 thumbnails

Answer (score 0):

Well, it isn't finished, but here's your baseline code:

http://jsfiddle.net/yTyZ5/

You'll need to do things like handle wrapping & whatnot, which may mean moving elements around depending on exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: wow, i cannot believe you went ahead to code it, don't mean to sound like an ingrate but i've only just decided on my own(a few weeks ago) to pick up jquery, and having seen what you wrote, i'm afraid my skills are not yet good enough to comprehend fully.. :(

Comment: Heh.  It was 15 minutes of code, and definitely isn't complete... but it should be a good start. Let me know what you might be having issues with.

Comment: Oh, and I was annoyed that Neal just wasn't getting it.  ; )